# A proof of Krein-Milman theorem

Tags: convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

**Disclaimer**

This thread is meant to record. See: [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762).

Anyway, it is written as problem. Have fun! :)

---

> Let $X$ be a locally convex Hausdorff topological vector space. Let $A$ be a nonempty convex compact in $X$. Then
>
> - The set of extreme points of $A$ is not empty.
> - $A$ is a closure of the convex hull of its extreme points.

**Remark:**

- If $A$ is a face of $B$ and $B$ a face of $C$, then $A$ is a face of $C$.
- If $a$ is an extreme point of $B$ and $B$ a face of $C$, then $a$ is an extreme point of $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition:** A nonempty set $F$ is a *face* of $A$ if whenever $\alpha x+(1-\alpha) y \in F$, for some $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$ and $x, y \in A$ then $x, y \in F$.

**Lemma:** Take any element $\ell \in X'$ (continuous linear functional). We claim that a set $F_{\ell}:=\left\{y \in A \mid \ell(y)=\max _{x \in A} \ell(x)\right\}$ is a face of $A$.

---

Let $\mathcal F$ be the collection of all **compact** faces of $A$. Then $A \in\mathcal F$ and thus $\mathcal F \neq \emptyset$. We endow $\mathcal F$ with a partial order $<$ such that $F_1<F_2\iff F_2 \subset F_1$. Let $(F_i)_{i\in I}$ be a chain in $\mathcal F$. First, $\bigcap_{i\in I} F_i$ is compact. If $\alpha x+(1-\alpha) y \in \bigcap_{i\in I} F_i$, for some $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$ and $x, y \in A$, then $\alpha x+(1-\alpha) y \in F_{i}$ for all $i \in I$. Because $F_{i}$ is a face of $A$ for all $i \in I$, then $x, y\in F_{i}$ for all $i \in I$. Hence $x,y\in\bigcap_{i\in I} F_i$. So $\bigcap_{i\in I} F_i$ is a face of $A$. It follows that $\bigcap_{i\in I} F_i$ is an upper bound of $(F_i)_{i\in I}$.

Then $(\mathcal F, <)$ satisfies conditions in Zorn's lemma. Thus it contains a maximal element $F^*$. Of course, $F^*$ is a compact face of $A$. If $x,y\in F^*$ such that $x \neq y$, then by Hahn-Banach theorem, there is $\ell \in X'$ such that $\ell (x) > \ell (y)$. By our lemma, $F_{\ell}:=\left\{y \in F^* \mid \ell(y)=\max _{x \in A} \ell(x)\right\}$ is a face of $F^*$ and compact. Assume $\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y \in F_\ell$ for some $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$ and $x, y \in A$. Then $x,y \in F^*$ because $F_\ell \subsetneq F^*$ and $F^*$ is a face of $A$. This combines with the fact that $F_\ell$ is a face of $F^*$ gives $x,y\in F_\ell$. Hence $F_\ell$ is a face of $A$, which is a contradiction. Hence $F^*$ is a singleton containing an extreme point.

Let $E$ be the set of all extreme points of $A$. Clearly, $\overline{\operatorname{conv} A} \subseteq A$ is convex. If $\overline{\operatorname{conv} A} \subsetneq A$. Then there is $a \in A \setminus \overline{\operatorname{conv} A}$. By Hahn-Banach theorem, there is $\ell \in X'$ such that $\max_{x\in \overline{\operatorname{conv} A}} \ell (x) <\ \ell (a)$. Let $F_{\ell}:=\left\{y \in A \mid \ell(y)=\max _{x \in A} \ell(x)\right\}$. Then $F_\ell$ is non-empty compact convex. As shown previously, $F_\ell$ has an extreme point $b$. Clearly, $b \notin \overline{\operatorname{conv} A}$. Moreover, $F_\ell$ is a face of $A$. So $b$ is also an extreme point of $A$, which is a contradiction.